# How to find shared values in rows from specific columns in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, duplicates

In my dataset (which is quite large 70,000 rows) I have two features "days_on_the_market_last_broker" and "days_on_the_market_all_broker". These two features have many rows that share the same value.

I want to count all rows that DO share the same values on the two columns and all the rows that DO NOT. How would I do this?

| days_on_the_market_last_broker | days_on_the_market_all_broker |
| --- | --- |
| 79 | 79 |
| 110 | 110 |

I tried working with the duplicate function but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to make a flag and filter it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[79, 100, 0], 'B':[79, 100, 20]})
## Flag for duplicated columns
df['duplicated'] = np.where(df.A == df.B, True, False)
## Filter out a new flag
df.query('duplicated == True').head()
```

Comment: If the second and third arguments of `np.where` are boolean, then in general you don't need to / shouldn't use `np.where` at all, and instead just use the boolean directly: just do `df['duplicated'] = (df.A == df.B)`

Comment: Actually you don't need `df['duplicated']` at all, nor `.query`, you can filter with indexing directly: `df = df[df.A == df.B]`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the counts:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[79, 100, 0], 'B':[79, 100, 20]})

number_equal = (df['A'] == df['B']).sum()
number_notequal = len(df.index) - number_equal
```

Comment: This is my first time using StackOverflow so I'm not sure how to markdown as code (CTRL + K doesnt work). But to answer your question: Yes, i just want the counts of how many values are shared throughout the two columns and the counts of those that differentiate from eachother. Your solution seems to point me in the right direction but by printing "number_equal" and "number_notequal" i simply get 0 and 1...

Comment: I'm only getting 0 and 1 since I'm inputting                                                               
({"A":["days_on_the_market_latest_broker"], "B":["days_on_the_market_all_broker"]})

Comment: @NiklasLP You shouldn't be getting just 0 and 1. But I don't understand what you mean when you say *"I'm inputting ({"A":["days_on_the_market_latest_broker"], "B":["days_on_the_market_all_broker"]})"*.

Comment: @NiklasLP I called the two columns `'A'` and `'B'` in my answer to make it shorter and consistent with GedasMiksenas ' answer, but if your columns are called `'days_on_the_market_last_broker'` and `'days_on_the_marker_all_broker'` instead of `'A'` and `'B'`, then of course you should write `'days_on_the_market_last_broker'` and `'days_on_the_marker_all_broker'` instead of `'A'` and `'B'`.

Comment: @NiklasLP, so, for `df`, use your actual DataFrame, not the mock DataFrame with three rows that I made in my answer; and then write `number_equal = (df['days_on_the_marker_last_broker'] == df['days_on_the_market_all_broker']).sum()`